# What is the this part of the sentence called?

Tags: syntax

The sentence is:

> We apologise for the destruction of your property by our workers.

What would the "by our workers" part be called?

It seems similar to the passive sentence structure where "by our workers" would be the subject. But the "destruction of your property by our workers" is a phrase and not a sentence so I am not too sure. Could someone tell me what would the "by our workers" part be called?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspect, the *by* preposition phrase has the same sense it has in a passive clause.

Nouns can have complements just as verbs can—especially nouns which are derived from verbs. That sort of noun typically takes most of the same sorts of complements as the verb it is derived from.

In some cases the complement takes a different form. The Patient of a verb is typically expressed by an *of* preposition phrase with the derived noun, and the Agent subject of an active verb is expressed by a possessive with the derived noun:

> ... the workers destroy our property ...
>   ↓
>   ... the worker**'s** destruction **of** our property ...

But this can also be cast in a sort of 'nominal passive': the Patient subject may be expressed *either* a possessive *or* an *of* preposition phrase, and the Agent is expressed the same way as it is with a verbal passive—with a *by* preposition phrase:

> ... our property is destroyed by the workers ...
>   ↓
>   ... our property**'s** destruction **by** the workers ... *or*
>   ... the destruction **of** our property **by** the workers ...

Comment: I see, so would it be correct to say if the sentence was changed to "We apologise for the destruction of your property", then the agent of the noun complement was omitted?

Comment: @dngr193 That's right. The reader would probably *infer* that the apologizing party was the agent of the destruction, because one doesn't generally apologize for actions for which one isn't responsible.